# Spark Scala - Duration to Mins on Spark Dataframe column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a df that has column which is duration representation as string like `PT2H`. I want to create a new column minutes_int which can be done in scala using -

```
import java.time.Duration
Duration.parse('PT2H').toMinutes()
```

How can I do this on entire column? I get an error when I do -

```
jsonDF.withColumn("minutes_int", Duration.parse(col("duration_str")).toMinutes())
```

Error -

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: CharSequence
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a User Defined Function to do this, although noting these don't get optimised so you may benefit from writing your own Spark only version.

```
import java.time.Duration
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
def durationToMinutes(duration:String) = Duration.parse(duration).toMinutes()
val durationToMinutesUDF = udf(durationToMinutes _)
```

And then to use it...

```
jsonDF.withColumn("minutes_int", durationToMinutesUDF(col("duration_str")))
```

Note you can also register this so you can use it in SQL, i.e.

```
spark.udf.register("duration_to_minutes",durationToMinutesUDF)
jsonDF.registerTempTable("json_df")
spark.sql("select duration_to_minutes(duration_str) from json_df")
```